# How to fix failure of generation of maven project in vs code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

During creation of a maven project in **visual studio code** using **'Maven for Java'** extension, I get the following error:

**[ERROR]** Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.4 is not configured

**[ERROR]**         Property groupId is missing.

**[ERROR]**         Property artifactId is missing.

**[ERROR]**         Property package is missing.

This works fine for me in another system.

The difference which I see in both console logs is that, in the one where it is not working have following statement :
**Generating project in Batch mode**.

But in the correct one it is like following: 
**Generating project in Interactive mode**, and the console waits for the user to enter groupId,artifactId and package.

I expect that in both environments, Interactive mode should work.
Is there some setting required to run maven generate command in interactive mode ? or what could be the possible solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the differences between the maven configuration settings in both the environments.

The one in which the interactive mode is not working (batch mode is working), I had the following configuration in the settings.xml of maven:

```
<interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>
```

due to which I was not able to get the interactive mode for creation of maven projects.
After commenting the line, it works fine.